# Пройтись по флажкам и найти среди них отмеченный

Tags: javascript, html

Есть тестовый HTML с 5 флажками `<input type="radio">`

```
<div class='container'>

  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>один
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>два
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>три
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>четыре
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>пять

</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
a = document.querySelectorAll('input');
console.log('a',a); // возвращает 5 элементов input

function listen(){
    for (elem in a){
        if (elem.checked == true){
            console.log(true);
        } 

        else {
            console.log(false); // возвращает false 11 раз
        }
    }

    for (elem in a){
    console.log('elem.checked = ',elem.checked); // возвращает elem.checked = undefined 11 раз
        }
}
```

Почему в функции возвращается 11 элементов и в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы итерируете по названиям свойств объекта `а` (который не является массивом), то есть - по строкам. У всех этих строк свойство `checked` - `undefined`, то есть - не равно `true`.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input');
//console.log('a', a); // возвращает 5 элементов input
for (elem in a) {
  console.log(typeof elem, elem);
}

function listen() {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i].checked);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>один
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>два
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>три
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>четыре
  <input type='radio' name='azaza' onchange='listen();'>пять

</div>
```